# Swami Vivekananda Commentaries on Sita

Tags: sita, vivekananda

Sri Rama was an  Avatar of God Vishnu. Sita, his wife, was also an  avatar of Goddess Lakshmi.

Sita personifies the ideal wife in the epic, Valmiki Ramayana. She complemented Sri Rama in every aspect of life.

The values that  Sita  enshrined and adhered to, at every point  in the course of a demanding life,  as exemplified in  the Valmiki Ramayana,  are also the values of
womanly virtue held sacred by countless generations.
The great monk, Swami Vivekananda described the immortality of  Sita’s story as under :-

"All our mythology may vanish, even our Vedas may depart, and our Sanskrit language may vanish for ever, but so long as there will be five Hindus living, even if only seeking the most vulgar patois, there will be the story of Sita present."

Are there any written works or commentaries where the great monk, Swami Vivekananda has talked about Goddess Sita?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Devi Sita (सिता) is also known as Vaidehi, Janaki, Maithili (वैदेही , जानकी ,मैथिलि)  is the central female character of the Hindu epic Ramayana.She was the daughter of "king Janaka". Devi Sita is described as the daughter of the earth goddess Bhumi and wife of "Shree Rama".

Yes , Swami Vivekananda has talked about Sita in his lectures. These are few quotes I came across   from The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda.

Below is from [**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/Notes_Taken_Down_In_Madras,_1892-93)/Volume 6/Notes Of Class Talks And Lectures/Notes Taken Down In Madras, 1892-93, by Shree Swami Vivekananda On Devi Sita.

> - Sita—to say that she was pure is a blasphemy. She was purity itself embodied—the most beautiful character that ever lived on earth.
> - A Bhakta should be like Sita before Rama. He might be thrown into all kinds of difficulties. Sita did not mind her sufferings; she
>     centreed herself in Rama.

---

> - What to speak of [**Sita**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WI1RDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT694&lpg=PT694&dq=What%20to%20speak%20of%20Sita?%20You%20may%20exhaust%20the%20literature%20of%20the%20world%20that%20is%20past,%20and%20I%20may%20assure%20that%20you%20will%20have%20to%20exhaust%20the%20literature%20of%20the%20world%20of%20the%20future,%20before%20finding%20another%20Sita.&source=bl&ots=D-yzNSBo4l&sig=ACfU3U1ZGQ-k_m8dqOOBH9513ZrvdJs6Zw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5lNLP2I3gAhUItI8KHaJ4CfwQ6AEwAHoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=What%20to%20speak%20of%20Sita%3F%20You%20may%20exhaust%20the%20literature%20of%20the%20world%20that%20is%20past%2C%20and%20I%20may%20assure%20that%20you%20will%20have%20to%20exhaust%20the%20literature%20of%20the%20world%20of%20the%20future%2C%20before%20finding%20another%20Sita.&f=false)? You may exhaust the literature of the
>     world that is past, and I may assure that you will have to exhaust the
>     literature of the world of the future, before finding another Sita.

---

> - Sita is the name  in India for everything that is good, pure, and holy; everything that in woman we call woman. [**Sita**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KjmXDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=Sita%20is%20the%20name%20in%20India%20for%20everything%20that%20is%20good,%20pure,%20and%20holy;%20everything%20that%20in%20woman%20we%20call%20woman.%20Sita%E2%80%94%20the%20patient,%20all%20suffering,%20ever-faithful,%20ever-pure%20wife!%20Through%20all%20the%20suffering%20she%20had,%20there%20was%20not%20one%20harsh%20word%20against%20Rama.%20Sita%20never%20returned%20injury.%20Be%20Sita.%5C&source=bl&ots=PKhwcw4S8W&sig=ACfU3U3CYeq0xkomAFLCEvRT3cFEJ14kIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9h8fX2o3gAhUVaI8KHR9kAjkQ6AEwAHoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Sita%20is%20the%20name%20in%20India%20for%20everything%20that%20is%20good%2C%20pure%2C%20and%20holy%3B%20everything%20that%20in%20woman%20we%20call%20woman.%20Sita%E2%80%94%20the%20patient%2C%20all%20suffering%2C%20ever-faithful%2C%20ever-pure%20wife!%20Through%20all%20the%20suffering%20she%20had%2C%20there%20was%20not%20one%20harsh%20word%20against%20Rama.%20Sita%20never%20returned%20injury.%20Be%20Sita.%5C&f=false) — the
>     patient, all suffering, ever-faithful, ever-pure wife! Through all the
>     suffering she had, there was not one harsh word against Rama. Sita
>     never returned injury. Be Sita.

Comment: Nice answer. There is no parallel to Goddess Sita..But some fools put her in the category of pancha Kanya category category viz mandodari, Tara, draupadi etc....These women though great can't even be compared to dust on the feet of Goddess Sita...Alas some fools will never listen.

Comment: @Krishna - Namaste , Very thanks for encouraging comment. Its the company of very nice people like you ,is what  I most  like  on this site. 
You are very right "There is no parallel to Goddess Sita"

Comment: Who's the author of Janaki Stuti? Vivekananda? If not, what it has to do with OP's question?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar In that case, you should probably move the Janaki Stuti to the end since it gives the wrong impression that Vivekananda composed it. Also, from [this answer on meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/126/2995), you should avoid "expressing our love and respect for our personal gods or gurus on the bottom of our answers."

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Also, try to avoid quoting from blogs, see [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/621/2995) on meta. Instead quote directly from [The Complete Works of
 Swami Vivekananda](http://belurmath.org/complete_works_of_swami_vivekananda/).

Comment: Btw @SwiftPushkar the site is now down :D

Comment: सीता,  not सिता.  and मैथिली Kindly correct.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the following two sayings of Swami Vivekananda on Sita in the book "Pearls of Wisdom - Swami Vivekananda":

> Sita has gone into the very vitals of our race. (III.256)
>
> Sita is there in the blood of every Hindu man and woman; we are all
>   children of Sita. (III.256)

This book has collected some of his sayings from his several lectures and the Complete Works. The citations like III.256 are referring to the locations in his Complete Works.